# Submit each form to a separate tab using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two forms (or any number of forms), and I want submit them separately with jQuery.

I try such code, but it opens just one new tab, and submits all forms to one tab.

How can I open a separate tab for each submitted form?

Here is the code:

```html
<button type="button" id="b">submit all</button>
<script>
  $('#b').click(function() {
    $('form').each(function (i, form) {
      $(form).submit();
    });
  });
</script>

<form action="gbattribs.php" method="post" name="photos"  target="_blank">
     <input type="text" name="attr_name[1]" value="color" class="inquiryTextFieldAttrib">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange" name="updatebut_x" value="Update">
</form>

<form action="gbattribs.php" method="post" name="photos"  target="_blank">
     <input type="text" name="attr_name[1]" value="color" class="inquiryTextFieldAttrib">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange" name="updatebut_x" value="Update">
   </form>
```

I tried this code, but it did not help:

```html
<script>
  $('#b').click(function() {
    $(':submit').each(function (i, s) {
      $(s).click();
    });
  });
</script>
```

It looks like it works in Firefox and doesn't work in Google Chrome.

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/qgm6bx8t/

Comment: Give them different targets.  `_blank` doesn't mean "open in a new window", it means "open in a window with a reference of _blank".  So the first form will open a new window as one does not exist with that reference.  For the second form, the window will exist so it goes to the same one.

Comment: I try rename target to _blank1 and _blank2 but didn’t help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qxo3pyrh/  Works for me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qgm6bx8t/ I need bulk submit, looks firefox open each tab for each form, but chrome doesn't

Comment: @Taplar — You're wrong. `_blank` is a special name: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#valid-navigable-target-name-or-keyword

Comment: Chrome will open all windows after giving it permission to open pop-ups and redirects. It's off by default, and rightly so.